# Define variables in a batch file when opening it

Tags: variables, batch-file, parameters, copy

I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there any way to define variables in a batch file when opening it via a command line? For example, when you open Google Chrome you can specify a page to open as a 'parameter'.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

I want to make a batch file that uses a copy command and takes the source and destination from variables that I define when opening the batch file.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters in batch:

#### Sample.bat

```
@echo off
if "%*"==""(
Echo There are no parameters
goto :eof
)
Echo.
Echo Param 1:            %1
Echo And Param 2...      %2
Echo Param 3 -------     %3
Echo.
Echo All Params # %* #
Echo.
```

#### Cmd Window

```
C:\> Sample.bat
There are no parameters

C:\> Samble.bat ABC DEF GHI

Param 1:            ABC
And Param 2...      DEF
Param 3 -------     GHI

All Params # ABC DEF GHI #


C:\> Sample.bat Test

Param 1:            Test
And Param 2...      
Param 3 -------     

All Params # Test #
```

You get the point.

Mona

Answer (score 0):

You can access command-line parameters via `%1`, `%2`, etc.

So a batch file containing

```
@copy %1 %2
```

would do just that.

Comment: If you give examples of what you want to do with your variables then it is easier for everyone. For EG: are you passing the source and destination on the command line, or will they be permanently defined within the batch file?

Comment: I want to define the source and destination **in** the command line.